# How to go back to standard ubuntu after having tested kde-standard?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, kde

I wanted to have a look at kubuntu, so I did install the package kde-standard.

I have now removed it and issued a `apt autoremove` but in ubuntu I am still left with the icons, mouse pointer, windows styles, etc.. of Plasma and the desktop also feels a bit slower.. how can I go back to standard default gnome-based ubuntu?

There are some similar questions here, but they refer to much older versions of Ubuntu and seem to be ubuntu-version specific.

EDIT

- I have tried `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mono` but not effect
- top returns me a 99.7% CPU consumption of `baloo_file_extr`. I understood it is a KDE indexing service. Strange that `apt autoremove` didn't get rid of it. How can I remove it ?

EDIT 2

- I have tried to reinstall `kde-desktop` only to then `sudo apt autoremove --purge kde-desktop` and the same then for `dolphin` (whay wasn't removed automatically ?)
- After reboot... tada.. stuck with a Bluetooth issue "failed to send firmware data"
- in recovery mode "dpkg repair broken packake" didn't help, so I get the root prompt and issue a
  `apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs apt-get --reinstall install -y`

Now I got rid of the Bluetooth issue and the choppy system, but incredible I still have the styles/icons of KDE !!
I think I'll gonna make install ubuntu back from scratch...

Bottom line, **not** run `apt-get install kde-standard` in ubuntu 20.04 !! If you want to try kubuntu, better you do in a different partition or in a VM..

EDIT 3

- I noticed that if I create a new user, he has the standard ubuntu stuff.. how can I "reset" my user to use standard style/icons ?

EDIT 4 (solved)

- just run as local user:
- `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`
- `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme`

.....ahhhhh...

Answer (score 1):

A little late...

To completely remove the KDE desktop environment you can follow the following commands:

```bsh
# Reinstall KDE
sudo apt install kde-standard 

# Purge KDE 
sudo apt purge kde-plasma-desktop && sudo apt purge kde-standard 

# Remove KDE apps 
sudo apt remove kde-* 

# Remove KDE themes 
sudo apt purge *breeze* 

# I recommend reinstalling gnome
sudo apt --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

After running the above commands, install the gnome tweaks app:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open gnome tweaks:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

Navigate to Appearence --> Themes --> Application theme ---> Yaru

The change icons:

Navigate to Appearence --> Icons --> Yaru

And that's it!

---

Alternatively, you can run:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /
```

To completely reset everything.

Answer (score -1):

Too late now, but the only change to accurately remove packages that were installed by installing a desktop environment is to take note of all the packages that are going to be installed. Only this way, you can explicitly remove them all later if needed.

The reason is that many packages that are pulled in through the metapackage for your desktop are marked as "manually" installed. Thus, a "sudo apt autoremove" will remove almost no packages after the metapackage has been uninstalled.

For now, I would just remove all applications that you know came with the new desktop environment. Removing the "plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo" and "plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text" will revert your boot screen to the default.

Comment: Not sure how the downvote is argued...